# Binary difference between two files

Tags: c#, filesystems, binaryfiles

I am working on creating a versioning feature in our C# client application. Our application stores data in a local folder, the size of this data can range from 10MB to 4 GB. One option to build this feature is to create a copy of the whole folder each time I need to create a new version. This would take a lot of disk space.

I would like to find a utility which takes the binary difference between two files and saves the difference in a delta file. Then I could recreate all the whole folder based on the binary difference.

This would be similar to incremental backups in Sql Server, for example.

The application is built using .NET C# 4.0 both Win forms and WPF. We use XML serialization and Sqlite for data storage.

I am looking for a dll library that I can reference from a .net application. 2nd choice is to shell out to a command line executable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688504/binary-diff-tool-for-very-large-files

Comment: What specifically do you want? For example, are you after a utility library that can do this, or a standalone utility? Are you interested in writing one yourself?

Comment: Just a hint: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx

Comment: @TimSchmelter - not sure I understand how memory mapped files have any bearing on this - what did you have in mind?

Comment: @RobLevine: Not yet done, but i would try to use memorymappedfiles to compare large files on binary difference and write the difference to a third file.

Comment: I use xdelta for patching files between releases, although my files are much smaller. See http://xdelta.org/

Comment: How are you going to identify a line in the file. Delete line 3456, or delete the line where some property = 3456. Even a full case sensitive line comparison could be iffy. Have you conidered some sort of transaction file. So each write to the main file, you write something into a WhatIamAbouttodo file? Lots of other uses for something like that as well.